# How to easily redirect hg repositories?

Tags: mercurial

On git there is an easy way to configure the client to use different servers and protocols, which is great because it allows you to move repositories without breaking complex build scripts.

```
git config --global url.https://oldserver.com/aaa/.insteadOf git://newserver.com/bbb/ccc/
```

I am looking for a similar feature to mercurial.... anyone?

Comment: Can you please show or at least link to this git equivalent?  It might make it easier to figure out exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Perhaps `hg help config` and look for "subpaths". Is that what you're after?

Comment: It looks like Mozilla [invented a server-side version of this](http://gregoryszorc.com/blog/2015/04/30/automatically-redirecting-mercurial-pushes/), but I'm not sure about doing it locally.  I imagine you could hack something together with a local proxy... but that's rather ugly.

Comment: In my case I need this for cloning as I want to be able to migrate them without having to change the build logic. All the clients (build workers) do use the same config because is a NIS account, which allows me to change the config in a single place. This was great for git, but now I am trying to do it for mercurial.

Comment: (wrt my "subpaths" comment, Keven pointed out that appears to only apply to *sub*repositories; sorry)

Answer (score 1):

The closest alternatives that Mercurial offers are the `paths` config section and the `schemes` extension, which enables a `schemes` config section. Here, `paths` allows you to define aliases for URLs, while `schemes` allows you to define aliases for URL prefixes.

For example, if you add the following to your `.hgrc` or pass the config option on the command line:

```
[paths]
foo = ssh://example.com/path/to/real/foo
```

Then you can do:

```
hg clone foo
hg push foo
hg pull foo
etc.
```

Similarly, you can enable the scheme "extension" (it's actually built-in, you don't need to install anything, just turn it on) and use that to define a prefix:

```
[extensions]
scheme=
[schemes]
ourstuff = ssh://example.com/path/to/reporoot
```

And then you can do:

```
hg clone ourstuff://foo
hg push ourstuff://foo
hg pull ourstuff://foo
etc.
```

This is useful if you have multiple repositories underneath the same location. Note that you can also use `paths` and `schemes` combined, e.g.

```
[extensions]
scheme=
[schemes]
ourstuff = ssh://example.com/path/to/reporoot
[paths]
foo = ourstuff://foo
```